# What happens if I don't pay a ATAC bus fine from Rome?

Tags: italy

I am a resident of Sweden and yesterday I bought a bus ticket to travel with the local bus here in Rome, long story short, although I had the ticket I did not know to validate it, meaning getting it stamped with a machine. For this I got a ticket from a non-sympathetic controller who issued me a fine of 50 euros.

She took my name, date of birth, personal registration number and country of residence.

My question is what happens if I ignore paying the fine? Will it reach me in Sweden?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to money.se. This Question seems to me borderline off topic. If you are looking for experience, travel.se might be a better place to ask - If you want to hear a legal opinion, i´d sugges law.se.

Comment: I doubt that it will exist for a mere ticket but to be sure, check to see if there is any legal reciprocity between the two countries.  FWIW, I got a hitchhiking ticket in Seattle Washington in 1971 and since I lived on the opposite coast, they never bothered.  It didn't prevent me from getting a DEA license either :->)

Answer (score 3):

Something of a general answer:

the classic case is when you get a parking ticket or perhaps speeding ticket...

It **"used to be" that there was zero chance of these following you across borders**.

If you were from the US, Australia, England or wherever - and you got a parking ticket or speeding ticket in Italy, Japan or New Zealand -  you'd just tear it up and subsequently laugh about it with your friends back home.

**However, this is very much in the old days.  As a broad general rule, infringements do follow you across borders these days.**

(Some 10-15 years ago, an Aussie friend got a parking ticket in Italy. He tore it up and laughed about it.  At that time, even, I said "Dude like me you are very old and living in the past.  The ticket will follow you as if it happened in the street next to where you live in Aussie."  Indeed that's exactly what happened. "the bad guys have computers now also"  :)  )

Particularly too, OP, your whole story is within Europe.

**In broad general terms, yes, these sort of things just follow you around now, as if it had happened in your home town.**

I get a huge number of such tickets, and I can generally vouch for this  :)

It would be really impossible for anyone to know the absolutely specific case; even if you phoned and asked someone there's likely a human element (maybe you'd escape some days, maybe not others).  But (sadly) "they have computers now". You're (very likely) screwed.